# Is it safe to call Type.GetType with an untrusted type name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security

I came across the following in a code review:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
if (type == typeof(SomeKnownType))
    DoSomething(...); // does not use type or typeName
```

`typeName` originates from an AJAX request and is not validated. **Does this pose any potential security issues?** For example, is it possible for unexpected code to be executed, or for the entire 
application to crash (denial of service), as the result of loading arbitrary types from arbitrary assemblies?

(I suppose some joker could attempt to exhaust available memory by loading every type from every assembly in the GAC. Anything worse?)

Notes:

- This is an ASP.NET application running under Full Trust.
- The resulting `type` is *only* used as shown above. No attempt is made to instantiate the type.

Comment: it could balloon your memory usage. can you not give a whitelist mapping from strings to `Type`?

Comment: +1 for a very interesting question. I don't know of any side-effects of GetType (like instantiation), but a canonical answer would be very interesting! Sidenote, I wish all questions were this clear, included all pertinent information *the first time* etc. A breath of fresh air!

Comment: No comment on safety, but this is not needed at all as it should be equivalent to `typeName == typeof(SomeKnownType).AssemblyQualifiedName`.

Comment: One theoretical potential that I see is someone being able to somehow drop an assembly onto the server (through some other vulnerability, or some file upload functionality, etc.), and then use this code to load that assembly. Not sure if it would be possible to execute anything, but look into [Reflection-Only Assembly Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331(v=vs.110).aspx) that doesn't enable execution.

Comment: @LB2 i had that in my answer too.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, I saw it afterward (about static constructor call, and see that it's not executed).  Hence I edited the comment to only keep option of reflection-only loading, in case it helps OP.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, this is not safe at all. [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w3f99sx1) will load an assembly if it has not been loaded before:

> GetType causes loading of the assembly specified in typeName.

So what's wrong with loading an assembly? Aside from it using additional memory as Daniel points out, .NET assemblies *can* execute code when they load, even though this functionality is not exposed to normal compilers like C# and VB.NET. These are called [module initializers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx).

> The module’s initializer method is executed at, or sometime before, first access to any types, methods, or data defined in the module

Just the fact that you are loading an assembly and examining its types is enough to get the module initializer to run.

Someone with a cleverly written assembly (say by using ilasm and writing raw MSIL) can execute code just by getting the assembly loaded and you examining the types. That's why we have [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0et80c7k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so we can safely load the assembly in a non-executable environment.

---

I did a little more thinking about this and thought of a few more cases.

Consider that your Application Pool is set to run 64-bit. Now imagine that your attacker uses the AJAX service to attempt to load an assembly that is strictly for x86 architecture only. For example, there is one in my GAC called Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication that is x86 only, there is no AMD64 counter-part. If I ask your service to load that assembly, you'd get a `BadImageFormatException`. Depending on what guard clauses you have in place around loading the assembly, unhandled exceptions could completely [bring down your AppPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx).

Comment: Code that you can't actually add with C#, nice! Good way to put in a virus that no one could ever find :(

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - That's a confusing statement.  You can find the code through disassembly or decompiling, which is how you would find any other code supplied in an assembly.  This is hardly any different than ages old PE based virses that would embed themselves in PE formats.

Comment: But are you going to *have* such a malicious assembly on your production server, and if so, wouldn't whatever security hole that got it there render this security hole rather moot?

Comment: @Servy I wouldn't take the risk. Module initializers are likely to exist in anything that was written in managed C++ (which is mostly why the CLR supports this feature) and they can end up in the GAC easily enough (supporting .NET Framework assemblies for managed C++ for example). Granted they probably do more harmless things, but it might be enough to crash the application to deny service. Taken into account that this problem is relatively easy to avoid just by loading the assembly in a reflection only context first.

Answer (score 4):

It could eat up memory potentially if the libraries aren't in memory.

I would have a `Dictionary<string, Type>` as an allowed list.

```
var whitelist = new Dictionary<string, Type>;
whitelist.Add("MyType", typeof(MyType));
```

Comment: Using your dictionary still requires creating a `Type` object based on a user defined string, so all of the same problems exist.

Comment: @Daniel: Are you sure `Type.GetType` invokes static constructors?

Comment: @MichaelLiu i'm pretty sure.

Comment: @MichaelLiu It does not.  Just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inherit danger in referring to the type itself.  Trust in .NET is at the assembly level.  If there's no available assembly that contains the specified type, your call will just return a null.  Accordingly, somebody has to make the assembly available for the code -- assemblies don't just appear out of thin air.

Comment: Is there any danger in loading an assembly that already exists on disk? (Assume that an attacker can't upload an arbitrary assembly, but maybe there's a security vulnerability in an *existing* assembly.)

Comment: @MichaelLiu I can't imagine why loading an assembly would inherently trigger code being run.  It just loads the assembly into memory.  That doesn't execute anything.

Comment: @Servy: I know that loading a native DLL will execute code in DllMain. Are managed assemblies different? And will `Type.GetType` refuse to load a native DLL?

Comment: Michael, consider this.  Maybe it isn't wise to expose your implementation (type names) within an ajax request.  Maybe it'd be smarter to pass an enumeration value and have your code evaluate it to find the type statically rather than dynamically.  Then your question becomes a non-issue.

Comment: @codenoire: Indeed. This is someone else's code that I'm reviewing.

Comment: @Servy Loading an assembly *can* certainly execute code as vcsjones shows. So that's certainly a possible weakness. Now it may not be a security problem in itself, but neither is a weakness that allows an attacker to write some file to disk (say with bounded size to avoid DDOS problems). But both of those taken together are certainly. Better to avoid it to begin with.