# Will prefixing a namespace to Type.GetType() mitigate security issues?

Tags: c#, security, .net-core

I'm wondering about the security of using Type.GetType() on untrusted input.

I have some classes in a namespace `A.B.C.Events` and would like to be able to deserialize them using `System.Text.Json`

this is what I'm currently doing

```
var type = Type.GetType($"A.B.C.Events.{TypeName}");
```

Am I opening myself up to the known issues of using Type.GetType() if I'm doing the prefixing like above?

Comment: Is there any whitelist in place? Are you restricting the characters to valid c# type names (alphanumerics only, no periods)?

Comment: Could you describe the security risks you are concerned with?

Comment: "...consider this. Maybe it isn't wise to expose your implementation (type names) within an ajax request. Maybe it'd be smarter to pass an enumeration value and have your code evaluate it to find the type statically rather than dynamically. Then your question becomes a non-issue." – [Xavier J May 27 '14 at 17:59](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895563/is-it-safe-to-call-type-gettype-with-an-untrusted-type-name#comment36791587_23895801)

Comment: If all the events that can be used are inside an assembly, you can easily enumerate them programmatically and check if `TypeName` is inside this closed collection, like `var events = typeof(A.B.C.Events.SomeEvent).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.Namespace == "A.B.C.Events").ToArray()`

Comment: Using `Type.GetType()` does leave you open to people dropping in DLLs and messing with your app, even using the namespace doesn't help as they can put their types in the same namespace. There are other overloads that let you control which assemblies are used though.

Comment: You can't prevent other DLLs from using the same namespace. Instead, you can restrict the assembly, e.g. by passing the full `AsemblyQualifiedName`, or by using `Assembly.GetType()` instead of `Type.GetType()`.

Comment: @gunr2171 Some more background: I'm storing things in a database table like: "TypeString,JsonString" so it's not in the context of an AJAX request. The vulnerability I'm worried about is remote code execution as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895563/is-it-safe-to-call-type-gettype-with-an-untrusted-type-name

I think xanatos's suggestion is good, I'll probably go for that.