# ReflectionOnlyLoad deprecated in .NET 6

Tags: .net-6.0

Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad has been deprecated in .NET 6. Is there an alternative?

What I'm trying to achieve is to find assemblies in the application path with a specific custom assembly attribute and load them. I can search for all assemblies and load them to inspect the attributes but I don't want unnecessary assemblies loaded into the app domain.

Comment: According to [this issue it never worked in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7273). It resulted in a full load instead of a reflection-only load.

Comment: In fact, the method [throws as far back as 5.0 Preview 1](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.0-preview.1.20120.5/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Assembly.cs#L348). The current CoreCLR Github repo doesn't go farther back as the repos were reorganized two years ago

Answer (score 3):

The method wasn't deprecated now, it never worked and throws a PlatformNotSupportedException since .NET Core 2.0. As [this issue explains](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/7273):

> Reflection-only loads are not supported in CoreCLR. (FEATURE_REFLECTION_ONLY_LOAD)
>
> Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad are doing full loads instead of reflection-only loads. They should throw PNSE instead.

The method's code [throws since the very first commit in 2018](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/03f6276420baa5bfb7e4f963d5f0d65a0c418d41/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Assembly.cs). The current CoreCLR Github repo doesn't go farther back as the .NET Github repos were reorganized 3 years ago:

```
public static Assembly ReflectionOnlyLoad(byte[] rawAssembly) { throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.PlatformNotSupported_ReflectionOnly); }
public static Assembly ReflectionOnlyLoad(string assemblyString) { throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.PlatformNotSupported_ReflectionOnly); }
public static Assembly ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(string assemblyFile) { throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(SR.PlatformNotSupported_ReflectionOnly); }
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question. The OP is looking for an alternative, not explanation why this API is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Lifting directly from https://makolyte.com/csharp-get-a-list-of-types-defined-in-an-assembly-without-loading-it/ (see the link for complete discussion about MetadataReader limitations):

```
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

var assemblyPath = @"D:\Projects\aspdotnet-background-dblogger\bin\Debug\net5.0\BackgroundDatabaseLogger.dll";

using (var sr = new StreamReader(assemblyPath))
{
    using (var portableExecutableReader = new PEReader(sr.BaseStream))
    {
        var metadataReader = portableExecutableReader.GetMetadataReader();

        foreach (var typeDefHandle in metadataReader.TypeDefinitions)
        {
            var typeDef = metadataReader.GetTypeDefinition(typeDefHandle);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadataReader.GetString(typeDef.Namespace)))
                continue; //if it's namespace is blank, it's not a user-defined type

            if (typeDef.Attributes.HasFlag(TypeAttributes.Abstract) || !typeDef.Attributes.HasFlag(TypeAttributes.Public))
                continue; //Not a public concrete type

            Console.WriteLine(metadataReader.GetString(typeDef.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

The other, possibly better, alternative (also mentioned in the post I linked) is the MetadataLoadContext package which hides a lot of low-level details: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.MetadataLoadContext

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this alternative. I didn't found if this also solve the security issue `ReflectionOnlyLoad` solved too ? (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23896200/13668671)