# Convert String Literals to .NET DataType to perform type validation

Tags: c#

Let's say at run time I get values like this:

```
  string expectedDataType = "System.Int32";
    object givenValue = "123 Not An Int32";
```

so I want to know if the value of that `givenValue`  is of the same type that we expected it to be which is declared inside `expectedDataType`
So in this case it should return `false` because that value is not an `integer`.

If it was not at runtime I could probably use the `is`  operator but I am not sure how with some sort of `reflection` I can do this at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Type.GetType` to get type object by name. And then to compare this type with the type of given object.

```
string expectedDataType = "System.Int32";
object givenValue = "123 Not An Int32";
object givenValue1 = 123;
Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType(expectedDataType)==givenValue.GetType()); //false
Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType(expectedDataType)==givenValue1.GetType()); //true
```

Important note - it may be unsafe to call `Type.GetType` with the type name received from an untrusted source. See [Is it safe to call Type.GetType with an untrusted type name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895563/is-it-safe-to-call-type-gettype-with-an-untrusted-type-name) for details.